# How to update status of data in SQL table when it has expired

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sql table. Every item has a column with the name 'expiredDate' with datetime type and a column with the name 'isExpired'.
I want to update 'isExpired'columns when ExpiryDate > Datetime.Now

Comment: This sounds like you are duplicating the data in the row - if you know the expired date, why do you need an expired flag?

Answer (score 1):

Use `update`:

```
update t
    set isExpired = 0
    where expirydate > now();
```

I'm guessing you want these to be "not expired".

That said, you don't really need both columns.  You could use a view:

```
create view v_t as
    select t.*, coalesce(expirydate < now(), 0) as isExpired
    from t;
```

Comment: Or use a Generated Column: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

Comment: @obe . . . Can't.  `now()` isn't allowed.